# Find Components Non Visual C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've tried numerous methods to list all non-visual components of a form such as OpenDialog, ImageList, TableAdapters, etc and could not find anything. To find the on-screen controls, I managed using Foreach in "Controls" screen but for those non-visual components I found nothing. I used the code below but without success:

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
           where typeof (Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
           let component = (Component) field.GetValue(this)
           where component != null
           select component;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that all those actually share a base class? I don't think they do. The fact that you can drag them onto the "non-visual" area of the form is just a fancy abstraction.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET `Do you have any evidence that all those actually share a base class?` I think OP has. They all share `Component` base class

Comment: @L.B Even given that; the OP hasn't said what isn't working in his code (hence my assumption).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
           .Where(f => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
           .Where(f => !typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
           .Select(f => f.GetValue(this))
           .OfType<Component>();
}
```

Comment: Note: This probably works only for those components that have the *Generate Member* option of the Forms Designer set to `true`.